# Session save folder redirection on shared hosting

Tags: php, session, permissions, fullcalendar, dreamhost

I am currently using shared hosting on Dreamhost for a gym booking system. It works whilst testing on a localhost. But on the host, the sessions crash the moment you try to do anything (For example subscribing to a class, the session is dropped and the user becomes logged out). The subscription to the class is also not sent through to the database upon logging in again.

Due to it being shared hosting, I have created a separate folder in the root (/ directory) and have used the following line of code in all files containing sessions in order to redirect them:

*ini_set('session.save_path','/home/dh_6sfkbj/session');*

With *session* being the directory we created in which to save the sessions. It has also been granted chmod 760.

I am using the fullcalendar JS library alongside PHP.

Currently, I believe the problem may have to do with permissions with the host, but cannot find any solutions. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

There are no errors recorded on the logs, just the usual missing robots.txt and missing.html

Here is some code with regards to how we've coded logging in:

ini_set('session.save_path','/home/dh_6sfkbj/session'); 
  if(session_id()==””){session_start();}

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
  { //Logged in code here }

Comment: any errors logged on the server? Also, seeing code relating to sessions / logging in/out is probably going to be relevant. Is there a session timeout setting configured on the server? What is the relevance of saving your sessions to disk - is this working, did it give you any insight? You say you did it but then don't say what the result was. There's not really enough information here to help you. P.S. fullCalendar is not a PHP package, it's a JS library, and unlikely to be anything to do with this.

Comment: The error.log file is empty, and upon trying out the system it did not log any errors to this day. We are currently using the default session settings which all worked on the localhost **as mentioned** so I believe the timeout is at the default 20 minutes. What's weird is that on refreshing the page, it keeps users logged in, but logs them out when trying to subscribe to a class